# $_POST foreach to add new outputs

Tags: php, html, foreach

The title probably is not very clear. So here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (is_array($_POST['value'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['value'] as $k) {
    echo "" . $k . "<br>";
    $k++;
    }
} else {
echo $_POST['value'] . " is not an array";
} ?>
```

Essentially what I want to do is input a string, lets say "Hello". I want the browser to output the string, "Hello" and then I will be able to input another string, "World". Then keep inputting strings and have the browser have the strings one after another like so...

Hello
World
etc...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't increment `$k`, that's why you have foreach there

Comment: Use several `<input type='text' name='value[]'/>`.

Comment: every php call is completely separate/independent of each other. if you want your form to keep track of previously entered words, you have to take measure to do that. hidden form fields, session variables, blah blah blah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use something like a PHP Session to store the values as they are posted and then output all the values one by one in a loop.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

session_start();
if(array_key_exists('value',$_POST)){
    $_SESSION['values'][] = $_POST['value'];
}

if(count($_SESSION['values'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['values'] as $value){
        echo $value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to post all data not only the new element you want to save because php does not store the `$_POST` permanent.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value[]" />
<?php
if (is_array($_POST['value'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['value'] as $k) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="'.$k.'">;
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (is_array($_POST['value'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['value'] as $k) {
        echo "" . $k . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo $_POST['value'] . " is not an array";
} ?>
```

Another way could be to serialize `$_POST`, but that into a hidden input and after sending the form unserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sessions:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['words'][] = $_POST['value'];

foreach ($_SESSION['words'] as $k) {
    echo "" . $k . "<br>";
}

?>
```